# How do I use a user input from another method in netbeans?

Tags: java, methods

I'm trying to get the user input from the method Salary so I can use it in TaxCheck.
Also if possible I would also like to add a new value named total salary which is the equivalent of

input user - corresponding deduction = total salary

```
public static double Salary() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 
    System.out.print("Input a salary: ");
    double inputS = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
    return inputS;
}

public static void TaxCheck() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 
    double inputS = Salary();
    double salary = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
    double salary1 = 15000.00;
    double salary2 = 20000.00;
    double salary3 = 25000.00;
    double salary4 = 30000.00;
    double salary5 = 35000.00;
    double deduction3 =  634.57;
    double deduction4 = 1624.57;
    double deduction5 = 2655.72;
    if (inputS>=salary5) {
        System.out.println("Rate Deduction: "+deduction5+"");
    }
    if (inputS>=salary4) {
        System.out.println("Rate Deduction: "+deduction4+"");
    }
    if (inputS>=salary3) {
        System.out.println("Rate Deduction: "+deduction3+"");
    } else {
        System.out.println("This salary does not have a deduction");
    }
}
```

Comment: The user input already works?

Comment: The input works but i don't know how to use the input in another method

Answer (score 0):

You pass the input/variable into another function by sending it as a argument.

See this line of code

```
 TaxCheck(inputS);
```

After sending it, you receive it into the other function by this line of code

```
 TaxCheck(Double salary)
```

In that function, the first input will be accessible by the variable name salary.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
            try{
             Salary();
            }catch(IOException e){
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }



public static void Salary()throws IOException{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 
        System.out.print("Input a salary: ");
        double inputS = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
        TaxCheck(inputS);
}


private static void TaxCheck(Double salary)throws IOException{
        double totalSalary = salary;
        double salary1 = 15000.00;
        double salary2 = 20000.00;
        double salary3 = 25000.00;
        double salary4 = 30000.00;
        double salary5 = 35000.00;
        double deduction3 =  634.57;
        double deduction4 = 1624.57;
        double deduction5 = 2655.72;
        if (salary>=salary5){
            System.out.println("Rate Deduction: "+deduction5+"");
            totalSalary = totalSalary - deduction5;
        }
        if (salary>=salary4){
            System.out.println("Rate Deduction: "+deduction4+"");
            totalSalary = totalSalary - deduction4;
        }
        if (salary>=salary3){
            System.out.println("Rate Deduction: "+deduction3+"");
            totalSalary = totalSalary - deduction3;
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("This salary does not have a deduction");
        }
        System.out.println("Total Salary = "+totalSalary);
   }
```

You pass the input of one function to another function as an argument. I'd suggest you to learn about passing arguments from one function to another in java. Hope i helped.

Comment: Sorry but i still don't know how to do that, this is just an extra homework i'm doing hoping i could get better at programming

Comment: @JonathanKedawenJr. Did you run the above code i gave you?

Comment: @JonathanKedawenJr. I've edited the answer and you can see how to send the input into another function.

Comment: Ooh i apologize i did not run the code when i wrote that reply, the code runs perfectly but can i also ask how to add a new value named "total salary" which is the equivalent of

input user - corresponding deduction = total salary

Comment: @JonathanKedawenJr. sure ill edit the answer to your needs, but it really is your homework and you should work on it. Also accept the answer if it fits your questions.